# toggle between iframes using dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i have an iframe , but the iframe src is being concatenated using javascript, so i am having a hard time figuring out how to toggle between two iframes using options from the dropdown list

**my code for concatenating the src for iframe :**

```
var str1 = "http://localhost:12341/";
var str2 = fx;
var str3 = ".html";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
var str4 = res.concat(str3);
```

**my code for using the concatenated variable for iframe src :**

```
<iframe id="showframe" scrolling="yes" height="290" width ="100%" src=""></iframe>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("showframe").src =str4; </script>
```

**Full Source :**

```
var str1 = "http://localhost:12341/";
var str2 = fx;
var res = str1.concat(str2);
var str3 = ".html";
var str4 = res.concat(str3)
console.log(str4);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<select id="check">
  <option value="Lot">Lot</option>
  <option value="Position">Position</option>
</select>
<iframe id="showframe" scrolling="yes" height="290" width ="100%" src=""></iframe>


<script>
    document.getElementById("showframe").src =str4;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that has display:none; and using jquery toggleclass function toggle one on and one off.

Comment: isnt there any simple way to do it in javascript ?

Comment: You can do it in JS too but it doesn’t get anymore simpler than jQuery